# "newish" [batch-script] is redundant with established [batch-file]: How does the synonym creation process work?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

***EDIT - Major rewrite after I read up about tag synonyms***

I originally proposed eliminating [batch-script](/questions/tagged/batch-script), but now I realize it should be made a synonym for [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file). I see that the suggestion has already been made, and I have upvoted the suggestion. Below is an explanation of why I believe it should not exist as a tag on its own, taken from my original question wording:

> The 1st question tagged with [batch-script](/questions/tagged/batch-script) was created May 2011.
>   Since then there have been only 171 questions with this tag.
>
> The tag does not have any wiki summary. I did a quick pseudo random
>   survey of the questions and every one looks to be perfectly suited for
>   [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), an established tag with over 3400 questions. The tag
>   [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) is reserved for Windows batch file (script)
>   questions. There is also the [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) tag with over 4000 questions
>   that is nearly synonymous with [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), though it is not
>   quite as focused in that it also has some questions that concern batch
>   processing in a general sense, not necessarily restricted to Windows
>   Batch scripts.
>
> I don't see how the relatively new [batch-script](/questions/tagged/batch-script) tag adds any
>   value, other than to give the few Windows batch enthusiasts like me
>   another opportunity for a tag related badge :-) Somehow I don't think
>   that is what tags are for.

Hopefully the synonym suggestion will be approved soon. But I am a bit confused as to what happens after synonym approval. What happens to the questions that have already been tagged with [batch-script](/questions/tagged/batch-script)? Are they automatically converted to [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)? or is a manual conversion required?

If manual conversion is required, how does one solicit help in performing the edits?

Finally, are rep points previously associated with the old tag automatically associated with the master tag?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable synonym to me, though I haven't done batch programming in decades.

Comment: @meagar - Thanks, I didn't know about synonyms. I've reworked the question.